# SpringBoot LDAP Authenticate manually

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, ldap

I have tried the gs-authenticating-ldap example against my LDAP server and worked.  I like to know how do the values from the default the FORM with user, password get pass to what class / method to actually do the authentication done?

Basically, I m trying find what class/method to call manually to request for the authenticate. i.e. `someclass.someAuthenticateMethod("myLogin", "myPassword");`